# Perhaps it's good to start accept food safety questions here?

Tags: discussion

As far as I understand, food safety questions such as "is it safe to eat X in mode Y" are associated at least with preventive medicine and  can well address general audience without mentioning a specific person.

- The `preventive medicine` data should likely be about antioxidants and/or antibacterial/antibiotic materials (for example, tocopherols and sodium benzoate respectively).
- The `curing medicine` data should likely be about antibiotic medicine and antidotes (for example, ampicilin and nitrophenyl psoralen)

I understood from the mod Carey Gregory that these are not allowed here and that leads me to try to understand:
Perhaps it's good to start accept food safety questions here?

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons we shouldn't accept food safety questions:

**Food safety questions are just another form of personal medical advice.**

Asking "Is it safe to eat honey?" is no different from asking "Is it safe to take NSAIDs?"

No matter how knowledgeable the answer, it could be dangerously wrong for the person reading it. The reasons why personal medical advice questions aren't accepted here are well documented and near-unanimously agreed upon for almost five years.

**The FDA sets food safety standards in the US. Similar agencies exist in other modern countries.**

The guidelines issued by those agencies are considered authoritative, so asking a food safety question here is really just asking us to search those sources for you.

You're not going to get reliable information here unless it comes from one of the authoritative government sites, so why come here? Just go to the source.

Comment: `really just asking us to search those sources for you` I suggest to change it to "for the asker" because as a general rule I would never desire to ask this. `You're not going to get reliable information here unless it comes from one of the authoritative government sites, so why come here? Just go to the source.` Similarly.

Comment: Besides that; what about an OP presenting minimal research effort and having a problem of misunderstanding a source about food safety and ask a question that will help her understand it? For example, in the past I misunderstood something in `man X` in Linux but professional Linux sysadmins were keen to explain it to me in simple words in Unix & Linux SE.

Comment: @JohnDoea A question asking for an explanation of something they found in their research is almost always acceptable even if it's about nutrition, food safety, etc.